# Having brothers established

Tags: meaning-in-context, subjects

> A complete change of life became desirable. He quitted the militia and
> engaged in trade, **having brothers already established in a good way in
> London, which afforded him a favourable opening**.

> Emma 
> Jane Austen 
> Volume 1 chapter 2

I want to know what's the subject of "established". Is it "having brothers" or the brothers themselves established? And what does "which" refer to?

Comment: "...because he had brothers who were already successful in business in London. This fact gave him a good opportunity."

Comment: Do you know that "established" can mean "growing or flourishing successfully", and it's not just the past form of "establish"?

Answer (score 1):

The "having" clause in the second sentence is essentially

> He had brothers who were already established ...

where the subject of "were established" is the brothers.

In this context "established" is what the brothers were, it's not a verb that needs a subject.

The antecedent of the pronoun "which" is the establishment, modified by
"in a good way".

The "Which" is in turn the subject of "afforded him".

(I am sure that's how to understand the passage. I hope I have the grammar right.)